# SQL Query to get a substring between [ ] in a string with multiple parentheses

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a column with text string named "Formula", where variables are coded with IDs and set into parentheses, text in parentheses can vary in length, the number of such parentheses is virtually unlimited. Data examples:

- `[a=5;b=1;c=15]`
- `[x=1;a=5;b=1;c=15]*[a=4;c=2]`
- `=IF([a=10232937;c=227634]=1;[a=2;b=51;d=14]*[a=1;b=51;d=14];0)`

I look for a specific combination of `a` and `c`, say:

```
Select Formula FROM Table WHERE Formula LIKE "%a=5%c=2%"
```

Result will be `[x=1;a=5;b=1;c=15]*[a=4;c=2]`although `a=5` and `c=2` are located in different parentheses in this case and the desired result is actually a null.

Any ideas on how to look within any given parentheses?

UPD: It's SQL Server 2014

Comment: UPD: It's SQL Server 2014

Comment: Can you explain why "%a=5%c=2%" doesn't give you what you want? Do you want it only when it's within a certain bracket [] ?

Comment: The absolute best way to deal with this is to stop storing delimited values in your database. This violates 1NF and is a serious pain to deal with. If you have a string splitter you could split this on "]" and then look for the existence within each parsed set. Here are several excellent splitters. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: find a TSQL Split function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Parse/Split function can help here

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, Formula varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'[a=5;b=1;c=15]'),
(2,'[x=1;a=5;b=1;c=15]*[a=4;c=2]'),
(3,'=IF([a=10232937;c=227634]=1;[a=2;b=51;d=14]*[a=1;b=51;d=14];0')

Select Distinct A.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Formula,']')  B
 Where RetVal Like '%a=5%c=2%'
```

**Returns NO DATA**

**While** `Where RetVal Like '%a=1%c=2%'`

**Returns**

```
ID  Formula
3   =IF([a=10232937;c=227634]=1;[a=2;b=51;d=14]*[a=1;b=51;d=14];0
```

The UDF if needed (logic can also be ported into the Cross Apply if you can't use a UDF)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Comment: This works well, thanks! Do you also know the solution for the string, where some brackets are inserted in the other brackets_

Comment: I mean such data: [a=5;b=[a=4;b=1;c=2];c=15]

Comment: @WhereVit Sorry this solution would not trap nested [].  I'll noodle it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming variables are always withing square brackets. The below code is checking for `[` and `]` in between `a=5` and `c=2`.

```
declare @table table
(
Formula varchar(max)
)

Insert into @table values ('[x=1;a=5;b=1;c=15]*[a=4;c=2]');
Insert into @table values ('[x=1;a=5;b=1;c=15;a=4;c=2]');

declare @search1 varchar(100) = 'a=5'
declare @search2 varchar(100) = 'c=2'

SELECT Formula
FROM (
Select Formula
, CHARINDEX('[', (SUBSTRING(Formula, CHARINDEX(@search1, Formula), CHARINDEX(@search2, Formula) - CHARINDEX(@search1, Formula)))) LeftPar
, CHARINDEX(']', (SUBSTRING(Formula, CHARINDEX(@search1, Formula), CHARINDEX(@search2, Formula) - CHARINDEX(@search1, Formula)))) RightPar
from @table
WHERE Formula like '%\[%\]%' ESCAPE '\'
) x
Where LeftPar = 0 AND RightPar = 0

--Output
--[x=1;a=5;b=1;c=15;a=4;c=2]
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the query returns an error either in substring or left/rightpar

Comment: I do not get any error, updated the query with sample data. Please run and verify.

Comment: I guess there is an assumption here, that there is always c=NUM before the brackets ]. In reality c=NUM can be also located in the middle

Comment: [a=4;c=5;b=1]*[a=6;c=4;b=1]